# How can I reset a cartridges save state for Metroid II: The Return of Samus?

Tags: metroid-2-return-of-samus

I purchased an original Gameboy version of Metroid II which, of course, is used.  I want to start my own game and I seem to recall there was a special key combination that you could press to clear the system memory.

How can I reset the save state so that I can start my own game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A similar [Metroid II reset question / answer on GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gameboy/585799-metroid-ii-return-of-samus/answers?qid=26020) outlines the method below:

> At the title screen, press <kbd>Select</kbd>.  Then, hold down so that the cursor is pointing at "Clear." While still holding <kbd>Down</kbd>, press <kbd>Start</kbd> to clear that saved data and begin anew.